# Javascript, Time and Date: Getting the next day, week, month, year, etc

Tags: javascript, datetime

Based on a given millisecond timestamp, what's the 'correct' way to get the next day, week, month, year, etc.?  That is, without having to do some kind of binary search with raw millisecond timestamp values or something silly like that.

**Edit:** Does using the Date constructor with a month, day, hour, etc. value beyond the limit translate it to the next year, month, day, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getNextDate()
  { 
   var today = new Date();
   var d = today.getDate();
   var m = today.getMonth();
   var y = today.getYear();

   var NextDate= new Date(y, m, d+1);
   var Ndate=NextDate.getMonth()+1+"/"+NextDate.getDate()+"/"+NextDate.getYear();
   alert(Ndate);
   }
```

Comment: Um, what happens if they day is 31 (or whatever the end of the month is) and you add 1 to it?  Does it correctly determine the timestamp you intend from that?

Answer (score 1):

If the millisecond timestamp that you have is (conveniently!) the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01 then you can simply create a new Date object from the millisecond value `new Date(milliseconds)` and use it as outlined in Misnomer's answer.

If your timestamp is based from onther point in time then you can simply workout the offset (in milliseconds) from 1970/01/01 and subtract that from the timestamp before creating the Date object.

As always when dealing with dates, be clear if you are dealing in local or UTC times.

[w3schools date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

[w3schools full date reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)